# How to handle the exception that is thrown while closing a connection in finally block?

Tags: java, database, exception

So, the scenario is that I am doing some database operations and finally commit/rollback and then connection close. But the connection close also throws SQLException.

In this scenario, what is the best approach?

1. catch and log it.
2. catch and throw an exception so that the calling function can handle it

In case of #1, the calling function will never know that something went wrong.

Comment: Finally commit/rollback is particularly weird. Generally an exception caught in the catch block can be suppressed but an exception thrown in the finally block leaves very little option but logging. `try-with-resources` handles most of this complexity for you.

Comment: What happened to option 3, i.e. handle it yourself. What, you don't know how to handle it yourself? Yet you expect the caller to handle it. Myself, I let the program fail and then look for a way to fix the code such that closing the database connection will not throw an exception, unless it is something I can't fix like, for example the database crashes, in which case what is the use of continuing with the application when there is no database available?

Comment: Use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 0):

This is covered by one of the basic rules of object-orientation, called 'Encapsulation', which insists that we don't expose a class' internal state to its collaborators. The effect of this on your problem is that a properly factored class shouldn't propagate SQL exceptions to the class using it (which is usually in a higher layer).

To be precise, the restriction is that you wouldn't expose SQL classes to a higher layer, and in the case of a 3-tier application, one would expect the higher-layer to contain business logic. Business logic shouldn't know anything about SQL -- that's what the database/repository layer is for. So, all SQL exceptions should be translated at the layer boundary.

The benefit of this approach is that you can swap out the implementation of your repository without having to change the rest of your system. You could theoretically replace the SQL with a no-SQL approach and clients of the repo need never know. Even if you did this at runtime.

In Java, we often ensure that we're not incorrectly exposing state, like SQL awareness, to different layers, by creating a separate jar file (maven module) per layer so that we can control a layer's dependencies. If we don't add the SQL library as a dependency on the business-logic library, then we will get compile errors if we reference it in that layer.

So, to fully answer your question, the repository layer should be dealing with database connections, and the client of that layer, the business logic, does not need to know about SQL errors. You should capture the exception and decide what to do with it within the database code. If you can't make a valid decision then you should create an exception for the higher-level abstractions (the business-logic) to deal with. How you deal with the specific problem is application-specific; if the tx has been committed, and you're running a single-threaded micro-service in a docker container, you might just log the problem and kill the container, but if you're in a GUI app that requires constant DB connectivity, you might throw a custom 'connection' exception to the business-logic layer which may generate an exception that is caught by the user interface to display the problem to the user for resolution.

Answer (score -1):

I think you answered yourself :
2. catch and throw an exception so that the calling function can handle it
Does this help ?

Comment: If you catch and throw from the finally block you elide any exception that the try or catch block might have thrown. This leads to particularly weird and difficult to diagnose problems. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2. Further catching an exception to throw it is generally unhelpful.